# How to stop numpy from iterating over custom Mapping objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

## The Question

Hi. Please consider this code

```py
import numpy as np


class MappingFoo:
    bar = {"a": 1}

    __len__ = bar.__len__
    __iter__ = bar.__iter__
    __getitem__ = bar.__getitem__


foo = MappingFoo()

print(np.array([foo.bar]))  # [{'a': 1}] (np array with dtype object)

print(np.array([foo]))  # [['a']] (np array with dtype str)
```

Note: `MappingFoo` implements exactly all 3 magic methods required to inherit from and become a `collections.abc.Mapping`.

Here are my **observations**:

- numpy treats `MappingFoo` like a list/iterable.
- If you remove any of the 3 magic methods of `MappingFoo`, `np.array([foo])` will also return an object array just like the first `np.array(...)` call.
- It makes no difference whether `MappingFoo` inherits from `collections.abc.Mapping` or not.

Here are my **questions**:

1. How does numpy decide which objects should be expanded/iterated over when creating an array with `numpy.array(...)`?
2. How do I stop if from iterating over my `MappingFoo` objects and make it store them as objects in the array instead? Remark: In my real example, I don't know the types of the input in advance. Hence, I want to use `np.array(...)` for array creation instead of relying on `np.empty(...)` and then filling it in a loop or other workarounds that require an explicit dtype.

### A Piece of Code to Illustrate Question 2

As the saying goes: a piece of code is worth a thousand words. So here is re-phrasing question 2 with code.

```py
from random import (
    randint,
    random,
)

def generate_input():
    """Generate a non-deterministic list as input for np.array.

    Generate a list or list of lists or 3-times nested list with either
        * only integers
        * a mixture of integers and MappingFoo objects
        * only MappingFoo objects
    """
    def generator(shape_, foo_it_all):
        if len(shape_) == 1:
            return [randint(0, 255) 
                    if not foo_it_all and random() < .99
                    else MappingFoo()
                    for _ in range(shape_[0])]
        else:
            return [generator(shape_[1:], foo_it_all)
                    for _ in range(shape_[0])]

    dim = randint(1, 3)
    shape = tuple(randint(1, 10) for _ in range(dim))
    return shape, generator(shape, random() > .5)
        

shape, input_ = generate_input()
array = np.array(input_)
print(array)
print(array.dtype)
print(shape)
assert array.shape == shape
```

How do I make the assertion pass each time without changing `generate_input` or making use of `shape`? Changing `MappingFoo` would be ok (of course not removing functionality). Lastly, `array` should have the minimum dtype required to hold the objects in the sequence.

Comment: Looks like you've found the control limits of `np.array`.  Apparently with those methods the input qualifies as a "any (nested) sequence".  As I (and others) have shown, the `empty/fill` is the only sure way of making an object dtype array with a specified shape.  Otherwise you are at the mercy of `np.array's` attempt to make a multidimensional (numeric) array.

Comment: "``MappingFoo`` implements exactly all 3 magic methods required to be a ``collections.abc.Mapping``." Note that it doesn't. It implements all *abstract* methods required *when inheriting from* ``collections.abc.Mapping``. A ``Mapping`` also must provide ``__contains__``, ``keys``, ``items``, ``values``, ``get``, ``__eq__``, and ``__ne__``. Even then, ``Mapping`` isn't structural – just providing the methods is not enough to satisfy ``isinstance(foo, Mapping)``; the class must inherit from or ``register`` with ``Mapping``.

Comment: Indeed. I phrased that badly. What I meant: it implements the methods needed for a `collections.abc.Mapping`. Of course it won't be a subclass of it, until it's a subclass of it. And the rest of the magic methods will not magically appear if the class does not have a metaclass that does that (or by other external means). I edited the question to be more precise. Thanks.

Comment: Actually there are various ABCs that do work structurally – e.g. ``Hashable``, ``Container``, or ``Generator`` – so that implementing "their" methods is enough to create a subclass, even without inheritance. ``Mapping`` isn't one of them, though, and its three abstract special methods aren't special for ``Mapping`` – a ``list``has them as well, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing import that almost made me quit:

```
In [31]: from random import random, randint
```

The thousand words code is only as good as the willingness of the users to run it.  Even so it's a good idea to give some sample outputs, not just the code.

For example the first time I tried this I got a (7, 2, 3) shape.  It wasn't obvious why.

Next time a simple shape:

```
In [32]: shape,x = generate_input()
In [33]: shape
Out[33]: (1,)
In [34]: x
Out[34]: [169]
In [35]: np.array(x)
Out[35]: array([169])
```

Again:

```
In [36]: shape,x = generate_input()
In [37]: shape
Out[37]: (4, 9)
In [38]: x
Out[38]: 
[[<__main__.MappingFoo at 0x7f8e123d81f0>,
  <__main__.MappingFoo at 0x7f8e238906a0>,
  <__main__.MappingFoo at 0x7f8e23890e50>,
  <__main__.MappingFoo at 0x7f8e23890ac0>,
  ...
  <__main__.MappingFoo at 0x7f8e123e67f0>,
  <__main__.MappingFoo at 0x7f8e123e6970>,
  <__main__.MappingFoo at 0x7f8e123e6100>]]



In [39]: np.array(x).shape
Out[39]: (4, 9, 1)    # and a dtype='<U1'
```

Using the empty/fill:

```
In [40]: res = np.empty(shape,object)
In [41]: res[:]=x
In [42]: res
Out[42]: 
array([[<__main__.MappingFoo object at 0x7f8e123d81f0>,
        <__main__.MappingFoo object at 0x7f8e238906a0>,
        <__main__.MappingFoo object at 0x7f8e23890e50>,
        <__main__.MappingFoo object at 0x7f8e23890ac0>,
        <__main__.MappingFoo object at 0x7f8e23890700>,
         ....
        <__main__.MappingFoo object at 0x7f8e123e67f0>,
        <__main__.MappingFoo object at 0x7f8e123e6970>,
        <__main__.MappingFoo object at 0x7f8e123e6100>]], dtype=object)
```

Since the `res.shape` matches the `x` list nesting, there's no need to iteration.  `res[:]=x` is enough.  Sometimes assignment like this can raise broadcasting errors, but that's not the case here.

Like I commented, `empty/fill` is the only sure way of creating an object dtype array with a chosen shape.  `np.array` is trying too hard to do its-own-thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to not use shape because in my real-world scenario, I don't know the shape (as mentioned in my question). If I want to know it, I'll have to iterate over the input which I wanted to avoid. But it looks like there is no way to avoid it...

Comment: the solution is go with something like

```python
shape,x = generate_input()
np.fromiter(x, dtype=object)
```